# Access Web App - How to update UI after changing data through data macro?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, ms-access-2013, ms-access-web-app

Let's assume I have an Access Web App with three tables: Group, Person and Task that would roughly look like this if using a normal Access client database:

[image: Exemplary data model]

In this app, data macros are run whenever the Task table is changed. If for example a new Task is added and a Person is assigned to it, the *Workload* field of the assigned person is increased by the *Estimated workload* of the task. Similar changes will be performed if Task entries are changed or removed.

---

Since my question is related to the user interface, I also give some details about the UI:

The view for the Group contains a "related items" control displaying all group members. This "related items" control allows to open a popup for a selected Person.

This popup - again - contains a "related items" control displaying all assigned tasks.

---

And now to my actual problem:

If I now edit the estimated workload of a task, the changes in the Person entry are actually stored in the database - but not reflected on the user interface until I manually reload the web page.

Therefore my question boils down to: **How can I make sure that that the changes, currently caused on the Person table by the data macros of the Task table, are reflected on the user interface without having to reload the page?**

Answer (score 0):

You need a UI macro that re-runs the query to get it reflected on UI side. The action is called [RequeryRecords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj248967.aspx).

[image]

You can leave out the "conditions" by leaving the fields empty, which just runs plain select query.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ic__hCctKi4) tutorial will help, it's a bit lengthy.

Comment: So there's no automatic way to cause this kind of update? I have to make a user click a button?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to have a button (although that might be helpful for other purposes). Simply add the requery to the "After Update" property of the field you are updating.